# How to exclude a directory in a recursive search using grep?

Tags: regex, grep

How to do a recursive search using grep while excluding a particular directory ?

Background : I have a large directory consisting of log files which I would like to eliminate in the search. The easiest way is to move the log folder. Unfortunately I cannot do that, as the project mandates the location.

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: `man grep | grep exclude`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

are you looking for this?

from grep man page:

```
--exclude-dir=DIR
            Exclude directories matching the pattern DIR from recursive searches.
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I sometimes forget, there is man page as well :)

Comment: Older versions of grep don't have this flag which is a shame :(.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate, if you can use `find` in your search, it may also be useful:
`find [directory] -name "*.log" -prune -o -type f -print|grep ...`
The `[directory]` can actually be the current directory if you want (just a `.` will do).

The next part, `-name "*.log" -prune` is all together. It searches for filenames with the pattern `*.log` and will strip them OUT of your results.

Next is `-o` (for "or")

Then, `-type f -print` which says "print (to stdout) any type that is a file."

Those results should include every file (no directories are returned) found in `[directory]` except those that end in `.log`. Then you can `grep` the results as you need.